# PrestaShop Validator: SQL security issues

Tags: php, mysql, security, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Good evening,
I'm validating PrestaShop on my form.
The mistake is reflected:

> Your module contains security issues. 
>       - Make sure that your data is always protected when doing an insertion. For instance, make sure that you do have an integer with an
>   explicit (int) cast, and that text is protected against SQL injections
>   thanks to the pSQL() method. 
>       - Be careful (string) is not a secured cast, you must pSQL.

The insert query I use are as follows:

```
Db::getInstance()->execute('INSERT IGNORE INTO '._DB_PREFIX_.'ff_list_filter (name, content) VALUES ("'.$t['filter_template_name'].'","'.  str_replace('"', '\"', serialize($t)).'")');
```

or

```
Db::getInstance()->execute('INSERT IGNORE INTO `'._DB_PREFIX_.'ff_people` (`field`,`list`) VALUES ("'.$c->email.'",'.$listId.')');
```

or

```
Db::getInstance()->execute('INSERT IGNORE INTO '._DB_PREFIX_.'ff_custom_field (field, list) VALUES ("'.$field.'"," ","'.$list.'")');
```

Have you ever seen anything like that?

Comment: Well you're not escaping your values, you don't want to distribute a module with SQL injections all over it would you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prestashop Addons validation process is very exquisite. This error means that you should cast all the external parameters you use in your SQL statement. Should be like this:

```
Db::getInstance()->execute('INSERT IGNORE INTO '._DB_PREFIX_.'ff_list_filter (name, content) VALUES ("'. pSQL($t['filter_template_name']).'","'.  pSQL(str_replace('"', '\"',  serialize($t))).'")');
```

If you have params with type is other than string you should cast directly to corresponding type:

```
Db::getInstance()->execute('INSERT IGNORE INTO '._DB_PREFIX_.'ff_list_filter (name, content) VALUES ("'. (int) $t['id_int'].'","'.  pSQL(str_replace('"', '\"',  serialize($t))).'")');
```

Additional suggestion. You could use more Prestashop's DB class in insert, update and delete sentences. This way avoid simple quotes errors or similar:

```
Db::getInstance()->insert('ff_list_filter', array('name' => pSQL($t['filter_template_name']), 'content' => pSQL(str_replace('"', '\"',  serialize($t)))));
```

Good luck.