# What is the non-casted variables in the SQL? [Prestashop]

Tags: php, module, prestashop

I made a module for prestashop. Addons team send me this message.

> You still have non-casted variables in the SQL queries, please make sur you carefully cast the variables in all the queries.

My module i'm using pSQL, int, float functions.  Is there something i have to do extra?

Thanks

Comment: is a practice that encourages their staff to prevent sql injection. Usually print a few, you can write them? PrestaShop module version?

Comment: for example:
public function getDefaultRates(){
        $sql_default_currency_rates = 'SELECT * FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'default_currency_rates';
        if ($currencies = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql_default_currency_rates)) 
and
Db::getInstance()->update('default_currency_rates', array('rate'=> (float)$user_rate,'checked'=> pSQL($checked)), '`iso_code` = "'.pSQL($currency).'"');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found myself in a similar situation, I have included here the error and I solved: [PrestaShop Validator: SQL security issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40914957/prestashop-validator-sql-security-issues)